# onchange event from select box to update field

Tags: javascript

On this page:
http://www.blackdownluxurylettings.co.uk/place_booking/2010-3-18,2

I am using an onchange event on the "number of days" select box to update the "departure date" field.

But currently nothing is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors? Can you post the code you're currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it this way using JQuery:

```
$("#ddlNumberOfDays").bind('change', mainPharmacy_Change)
```

Maybe for javascript, you should just try `'change'`.

Comment: As @Todd: pointed out, it should be bound to the SELECT tag instead. Don't forget to return false.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at it quickly: wouldn't you want the `ONCHANGE` event attached to the `SELECT` tag rather than the individual options?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the regular Javascript `onChange` event only fires once the select box loses focus AND it's contents have been changed. I don't know how jQuery achieves it, but their [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method will fire whenever the contents are updated.

Also, I get the following error in my Javascript console when loading your page:

```
[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
```