# django template: get dictionary's value based on the key that equals to certain tag's value

Tags: javascript, django, dictionary

I'm very new to web development and I know this might be stupid approach but cannot think of a better way of doing this. In the views.py a method returns a dictionary named `sniffer_aps` to the template in following format:

```
sniffer_aps = {device1:[ap1, ap2], device2:[ap3, ap4, ap5], ......}
```

In the template I have a dropdown list that lists all devices(device1, device2, ......).

In another field I list all aps belong to the device selected in the dropdown list. I want to dynamically adjust the field according to the device I selected, but it doesn't really work.

The dropdown list code is:

```
<select onchange="refresh(this.value)" id="sniffer_list">
            {% for sniffer_ap in sniffer_aps %}
                <option value={{ sniffer_ap }}>{{ sniffer_ap.plug_ip }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
</select>
```

My question is that how can I loop though the value in the field that shows aps based on the option selected in the dropdown list?

Right now my approach is to use javascript to detect the "onchange" event of the dropdown list, and change the value the field that list all aps accordingly, then just get the value of the field and treat it as the key of the dictionary.

```
function refresh(key) {
        $('.router').attr('value') = key;
}
```

For the field that lists aps, it is where the problem is. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="6">
                {% for router in sniffer_aps[this.value] %}
                    <option class="router" value="">{{ router }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Please correct my approach, or if somebody can provide a better way. Thanks very much.

Comment: You may want to check Jinja2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into trouble here because you're confusing server-side code (Django's templating engine) with client-side code (the Javascript code you're using for the `onchange` handler). Your server-side code will have run on the server before the resulting HTML is ever delivered to the client, so you can't have any interactions between client-side Javascript and the template logic.

You're right to use Javascript and the `onchange` event to update the values in the field that lists apps - you *could* do this on the server, by submitting the form and changing the HTML with Django when the new request is returned, but this takes a new webpage load and isn't nearly as fast or user-friendly as doing it with Javascript.

I would approach this by:

1. Converting the dictionary to JSON in your Django view class:

   ```
   import json
   ...
   sniffer_app_json = json.dumps(sniffer_apps)
   ```
2. Outputing the JSON as a JavaScript object in your template code:

   ```
   var snifferApps = {{ sniffer_apps_json }};
   ```
3. Using JavaScript to update the apps field, using this data. There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906305/update-dropdown-menu-values-depending-on-user-selection) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990552/javascript-change-the-dropdown-values-based-on-other-dropdown) [addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379709/update-select-multiple) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502859/onchange-event-from-select-box-to-update-field) on StackOverflow - you might consider using jQuery, as it makes this sort of manipulation much easier.

Comment: Nice suggestion nrabinowitz, sounds feasible, I will try that.

Comment: One more thing, in your suggestion, is it ok to use django template variable in javascript like {{ sniffer_apps_json }}?

Comment: Sure, as long as your sure that the output will be a valid JavaScript value. That's why I'm suggesting encoding as JSON first, which should get you a well-formatted object to use with JavaScript.